# Multi hook deploiement

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, events

Having this :

```
    <?php

class Planner_plugin{
    
    public function __construct(){
        add_shortcode('planner::display', array($this, 'display_planner'));
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Planner_plugin' , 'install'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'planner_load_scripts')); // chargement du script      
        ...
    }
    
    public function planner_load_scripts(){
        wp_register_style('planner_css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__)); //my style
        wp_register_style('opensans_css', plugins_url('css/open-sans_Font.css', __FILE__)); //Open sans font
        wp_register_style('fa_css', plugins_url('css/font-awesome.min.css', __FILE__));
        wp_register_script('planner_script', plugins_url('js/calendar.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), '', true ); // my script who generate a planner
        wp_enqueue_style('planner_css');
        wp_enqueue_style('opensans_css');
        wp_enqueue_style('fa_css');
        wp_enqueue_script('planner_script');
        wp_localize_script('planner_script','wp_included_vars', array(
                'date' => strtotime('now')
            )
        );
    }
    
    ...
}

$plugin = new Planner_Plugin();
?>
```

When everything is generated, i'll have multiple register for event listener (6 times) so it will trigger my function 6 time everytime i made an action in my component. But the hook "wp_enqueue_scripts" have to be triggered only 1 time, no ? How can i fix this ?

## EDIT

In my class, i have this too :

```
function display_planner(){
    ?>
    <div class="planner">
        <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar-header">   
                <div class="headerWrapper">
                    <a class="btn btn-prev previousYear">
                        <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="currentYear">July</span>
                    <a class="btn btn-next nextYear">
                        <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="headerWrapper">
                    <a class="btn btn-prev previousMonth">
                        <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="currentMonth"></span>
                    <a class="btn btn-next nextMonth">
                        <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

So when i refresh, the page, it will put multiple event listener to previous Month/year and nextMonth/years, as i said. But i have too javascript code, who generate my calendar as well, and by the javascript, it will be added only 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method - the `add_action` will fire for each instantiation, but the hook will only be registered once:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __CLASS__ . '::planner_load_scripts' );

static public function planner_load_scripts() {

}
```

Comment: it not solved the problem, i always have multiple event listeners for elements loaded by php. But for element loaded by javascript, i only have 1 event listener, as i need.

Comment: Okay I am officially completely lost. Can you try and re-explain your problem in your original question?

Comment: i've updated the post.